# Can't open my android emulator when i run expo start

Tags: react-native, android-studio, npm, android-emulator, expo

When I run expo start on my cli, I cant access my expo app on my android emulator. I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Gee\Desktop\SneakerShoppingApp\node_modules\metro-hermes-compiler\src\emhermesc.js:81
          throw ex;
          ^

RuntimeError: abort(Error: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
    at process.abort (C:\Users\Gee\Desktop\SneakerShoppingApp\node_modules\metro-hermes-compiler\src\emhermesc.js:796:13)
    at process.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at process.emit (C:\Users\Gee\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:439:21)
    at emit (node:internal/process/promises:136:22)
    at processPromiseRejections (node:internal/process/promises:242:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:97:32)

C:\Users\Gee\Desktop\SneakerShoppingApp>RuntimeError: abort(Error: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
'RuntimeError:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[image]

Please what can I do to solve this?